# Vuelidate checking for true/false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have a custom checkbox

```
<checkbox v-model="form.terms_accepted" />
```

The true/false value toggles fine

```
{
"first_name": "", 
"last_name": "", "username": "", 
"email": "", "terms_accepted": true 
}
```

How do I validate for a true value?

at the moment I my validation rule is.

```
terms_accepted: {
         required
},
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a simple function:

```
terms_accepted: {
  checked: value => value === true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
terms_accepted: {
  checked: sameAs(true)
}
```

works for latest vuelidate as of today:

```
"@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0",
"@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0",
```